# Text input control using css will not lose "Focus" style

Tags: css, input, hover, focus, styling

I have a standard input textbox that I've styled using css and psuedo-class elements Hover and Focus.  The css I am using is pretty simplistic:

```
.riTextBox:hover,
.riTextBox:focus
{
    border: solid 1px #F1C15F;
}

.riTextBox
{
    border: solid 1px #7394BE;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}
```

All is working great except when the textbox has text in it and is selected with the mouse,  and as you are selecting the text you leave the bounds of the textbox (with the mouse button still down), and then mouse up somewhere outside the textbox.  You will notice that the textbox border is still highlighted as if it never lost focus.

It seems that the onselect event of the textbox is conflicting with onblur, but I'm not sure.  See here to reproduce this frustrating issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/pBkhT/7/

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: "the textbox border is still highlighted as if it never lost focus" that's because it doesn't lose focus; if the mouse-up occurs outside of the element (certainly in Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04 and, from memory, IE 7 and 8/Win XP) it simply cancels the click in the element, rather than transfers focus to another.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Yes you are correct.  Bad wording on my part.  What I would like to accomplish is that the textbox loses it's highlighting style when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late, but it works for your problem. Simply remove the focus event that is coupled with the hover event. Your original hover border will still remain on focus (when user clicks the box), but when the user moves the mouse away, the hover styling will disappear, even when the mouse button is still down.

```
.riTextBox
{
    border: solid 1px #7394BE;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}

.riTextBox:hover
{
    border: solid 1px #F1C15F;
}
```